# Speeding web-scraping up Python 3

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get information from two websites and display it on 'real-time' in the console.

To get the information from the website I am using BeautifulSoup 4. I have read, that the bottleneck of scraping websites is the connection or the website itself. So I wanted to use multithreading, so the read can be done 'simultaneously'. Below is my code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import threading
import time




link_website_one = 'http://www.website1.com'
link_website_one = 'http://www.website2.com'



def request_url(url):
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.1 Safari/537.36'
    header = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }

    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=header)
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        return response
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        print('The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.')
        print(e.code,': ', e.reason)
        return None
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        print('We failed to reach a server.')
        print(e.code,': ', e.reason)
        return None


def new_entry(website, lis, arr, a_id):
    if website == 0 :
        info1 = arr.find()
        info2 = arr.find('div', {'class' : '1'}).find('span', {'class' : '7'}).get_text().strip()
        info3 = arr.find('span', {'class' : '2'}).get_text().strip()
        info4 = arr.find('span', {'class' : '3'}).get_text().strip()
        info5 = arr.find('span', {'class' : '4'}).get_text().strip()
        info6 = arr.find('div', {'class' : '5'}).get_text().strip() 
        lis.append({'info1' : info1, 'info2' : info2, 'info3' : info3, 'info4' : info4, 'info5' : info5, 'info6' : info6})
    elif website == 1 :
        info1 = a_id
        info2 = arr.find('span', {'class' : '8'}).get_text()
        info3 = arr.find('div', {'class' : '9'}).get_text()
        info4 = arr.find_all('div', {'class' : '10'})[0].get_text()
        info5 = arr.find_all('div', {'class' : '10'})[1].get_text()
        info6 = arr.a["href"]
        lis.append({'info1' : info1, 'info2' : info2, 'info3' : info3, 'info4' : info4, 'info5' : info5, 'info6' : info6})


class AsyncSearch(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, website, iter_rounds, delay_time):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.website = website
        self.iter_rounds = iter_rounds
        self.delay_time = delay_time

    def run(self):
        if self.website == 0:
            for z in range(self.iter_rounds):
                req_1 = request_url(link_1) 
                content_1 =req_1.read()
                soup_1 = BeautifulSoup(content_1, 'lxml') 
                arr_1 = soup_1.find_all('div', {'class' : 'special_class'}) 
                for x in range(len(arr_1)):
                    id_as = int(arr_1[x].find('class123')['class2345'].split(',')[0].split('"')[3].strip())
                    if id_as not in found_ids_1: 
                        found_ids_1.add(id_as)
                        new_entry(0, all_entries_1, arr_1[x], id_as)
                    #else:
                    #    break
                req_1.close()
                time.sleep(self.delay_time)

        elif self.website == 1:
            for z in range(self.iter_rounds):
                req_2 = request_url(link)
                content_2 =req_2.read()
                soup_2 = BeautifulSoup(content_2, 'lxml')
                arr_2 = soup_2.find_all('div', {'class' : 'class445'})
                for x in range(len(arr_2)):
                    if arr_2[x].a['oid'] not in found_ids_2:
                        #print('Mobile: ',test[x].a[Inserat_ID])
                        found_ids_2.add(arr_2[x].a['oid'])
                        new_entry(1, all_entries_1, arr_2[x], arr_2[x].a['oid'])
                    #else:
                    #    break
                req.close()
                time.sleep(self.delay_time)


all_entries_1=[]
all_entries_2=[]
found_ids_1 = set()
found_ids_2 = set()

website1 = AsyncSearch(0,10,1)
website2 = AsyncSearch(1,10,1)


website1.start()
website2.start()    

website1.join()
website2.join()
```

First of two lists (all_entries 1/2) and two sets (found_ids 1/2) are created.

The websites I am scraping are offering 20 ads per page with unique ids. With the new_entry method you can say which website you want, in which list it should append the new entry, which array contains the beautifulsoup and the id of the ad you want to append.

Now for the mutlithreading I created a class AsyncSearch, where you can choose the website, choose the number of iterations of requests and how long to wait for the next request.

The two sets found_ids 1/2 are there so you don't append an ad more than once in the all_entries list.

Now to the problem. This code works.

But: If delay_time = 1 and iterations = 10 it needs 20 seconds to finish. Is there a faster approach to solve this problem? the .read() duration is between 0.12 and 0.17 seconds for website 1 and between 0.03 and 0.10 seconds for website 2.

If I said anything not understandable please ask.

Comment: You should take a look at `scrapy`, which was made to crawl websites.

Comment: Is scrapy going to speed this up? Whats the difference between my approach and scrapy?

Comment: found this question on quora and it explains well, why scrapy is useful in this situation:
[Question on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-would-some-use-scrapy-instead-of-just-crawling-with-requests-or-urllib2)